# A question related to cell of UITabelview

Tags: iphone

UIButton * button;
I have put cell.accessoryView = button;

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath i have written above code,but it doesn't show UIButton on cell of UITabelView

Answer (score 2):

You need to put this in the delegate method `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` that initializes and returns cells for the table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // initialize cell and contents here, for the specified indexPath value
}
```

You might want to read the [Table View Programming Guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451), which explains this in detail.